# Google Maps V3 Label alignment

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've created a custom marker in google maps and want to set labels on it (1 & 2), but somehow I cant position it and it always positions wrong:

[image: picture]
<sub>(source: [bilder-upload.eu](https://www.bilder-upload.eu/thumb/2e16c3-1565260089.png))</sub>

I've already tried setting different anchors, but it seems like they wont move

```js
var t = this,
       markerConfig = {
           lat: location.data('lat'),
           lng: location.data('lng'),
           label: location.data('id').toString(), color: 'white'
       },
       iconSize = 0.45,
       icon = {
           path: "M53.1,48.1c3.9-5.1,6.3-11.3,6.3-18.2C59.4,13.7,46.2,0.5,30,0.5C13.8,0.5,0.6,13.7,0.6,29.9 c0,6.9,2.5,13.1,6.3,18.2C12.8,55.8,30,77.5,30,77.5S47.2,55.8,53.1,48.1z",
           fillColor: '#00492C',
           fillOpacity: 1,
           strokeWeight: 0,
           scale: iconSize,
           anchor: new google.maps.Point(38, 80),

       };
   t.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       map: map,
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(markerConfig.lat, markerConfig.lng),
       label: {
           text: markerConfig.label,
           color: 'red',
       },
       icon: icon,
   })
};
```

I expect it to align to the center of the markers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the position of the label with respect to the marker, use [`labelOrigin`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Icon.labelOrigin):

> **labelOrigin**
>   Type:  Point
>   The origin of the label relative to the top-left corner of the icon image, if a label is supplied by the marker. By default, the origin is located in the center point of the image.

related questions:

- [How to position the label inside the Marker in Google Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393756/how-to-position-the-label-inside-the-marker-in-google-map)
- [Google Maps API, add custom SVG marker with label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321440/google-maps-api-add-custom-svg-marker-with-label)
- [Google map label placement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47434579/google-map-label-placement)

`labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(30, 30)` works with your marker (and it looks like the `anchor` is slightly off, `anchor: new google.maps.Point(32, 80),` seems to work best.

```
var markerConfig = {
  lat: 12.97,
  lng: 77.59,
  label: "1",
  color: 'white'
},
iconSize = 0.45,
icon = {
    path: "M53.1,48.1c3.9-5.1,6.3-11.3,6.3-18.2C59.4,13.7,46.2,0.5,30,0.5C13.8,0.5,0.6,13.7,0.6,29.9 c0,6.9,2.5,13.1,6.3,18.2C12.8,55.8,30,77.5,30,77.5S47.2,55.8,53.1,48.1z",
    fillColor: '#00492C',
    fillOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 0,
    scale: iconSize,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(32, 80),
    labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(30, 30)
  };
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(markerConfig.lat, markerConfig.lng),
  label: {
    text: markerConfig.label,
    color: 'red',
  },
  icon: icon,
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/znew6pxs/17/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {
      lat: 12.97,
      lng: 77.59
    }
  });

  var markerConfig = {
      lat: 12.97,
      lng: 77.59,
      label: "1",
      color: 'white'
    },
    iconSize = 0.45,
    icon = {
      path: "M53.1,48.1c3.9-5.1,6.3-11.3,6.3-18.2C59.4,13.7,46.2,0.5,30,0.5C13.8,0.5,0.6,13.7,0.6,29.9 c0,6.9,2.5,13.1,6.3,18.2C12.8,55.8,30,77.5,30,77.5S47.2,55.8,53.1,48.1z",
      fillColor: '#00492C',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 0,
      scale: iconSize,
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(32, 80),
      labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(30, 30)
    };
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(markerConfig.lat, markerConfig.lng),
    label: {
      text: markerConfig.label,
      color: 'red',
    },
    icon: icon,
  });
};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
```